# Wordpress Plugin Optimize code

Tags: wordpress

Within a wp plugin, I see the following code on the php file of the plugin.

```
public function register_plugin_scripts() {
        /*** Styles ***/
        $cyclone_css = add_query_arg(array('cyclone_templates_css' => 1), home_url( '/' ));
        wp_register_style( 'cyclone-slider-plugin-styles', $cyclone_css );//contains our combined css from ALL templates
        wp_enqueue_style( 'cyclone-slider-plugin-styles' );

        /*** Scripts ***/
        wp_register_script( 'cycle', $this->plugin_url.'js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle' );


}
```

Now, I want to alter some of it. Right now, this plugin is used at every single page. Implying both the 1) combined css 2) jquery.cycle.all.min.js is requested each page. However, I only use this plugin for the main page. So how do I fix it, making the css file + js to only be loaded for the main page, nothing else.

Next, I do not want to combine css from all templates. Instead, it should be pinpointed to a selected location. How to do that?. Thanks in advance. Plugin is Cyclone Slider 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you were happy to edit the plugin code directly, it would be a simple matter of making the wp_enqueue_script() calls conditional on being on the home page.

```php
public function register_plugin_scripts() {
        /*** Styles ***/
        $cyclone_css = add_query_arg(array('cyclone_templates_css' => 1), home_url( '/' ));
        wp_register_style( 'cyclone-slider-plugin-styles', $cyclone_css );//contains our combined css from ALL templates


        /*** Scripts ***/
        wp_register_script( 'cycle', $this->plugin_url.'js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js', array('jquery') );
 if (is_front_page()){
      wp_enqueue_style( 'cyclone-slider-plugin-styles' );       
      wp_enqueue_script( 'cycle' );
 }
}
```

However, you almost certainly ***don't*** want to edit the plugin, because your changes will get overwritten when the plugin is updated.

I would therefore use wp_dequeue_script and wp_dequeue_style to get stop the scripts loading where you don't want them to.

Per [Wordpress Function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script), you could add this code in your theme function.php file or similar:

```php
 /**
 * Dequeue a queued script.
 *
 * Hooked to the wp_print_scripts action, with a late priority (100),
 * so that it is after the script was enqueued.
 */
function wpcyclone_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'cycle' );
   wp_dequeue_script( 'cyclone-slider-plugin-styles' );
}
if (!is_front_page()){
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpcyclone_dequeue_script', 100 );
}
```